# Cannot import JavaFx in intellij

Tags: java, javafx

I cannot seem to get JavaFx to import into Intellij always getting a "cannot resolve symbol". I have checked the files and I have the jfxt.jar file and have it enabled as a plugin in Intellij. I am using JDK 11 and Intellij version 2018.2.4 can anyone give me anything to try to fix the problem?

Comment: Isn't JavaFX enabled by default with IntelliJ? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-for-javafx-application-development.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using JDK 11 which doesnt come with javafx, so I changed my JDK to version 10 and it worked perfectly fine.